# How to recognize images in Unity with ARToolKit

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, image-recognition, artoolkit

I am using ARToolKit for recognizing some images. I made the official tutorial
https://github.com/artoolkit/ar6unity-wiki/wiki/Setting-Up-Your-First-ARToolKit-for-Unity-Scene
in this site. However, I do not need to track a object; I just need to simply recognize the image and done. Which script and line is recognizing the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a script and extend AAREventListener (or so, on the phone can't look up the exact name) then implement the onMarkerFound function. That will tell you when and which marker was found. Then add your script to ARTrackable in the inspector. It is the last edit field in the ARTrackable editor window